How should auth work in a microservice architecture?
We have spa (angular) + proxy (aspnet) and several microservices on AspNet (ms1, ms2...), as well as a separate service (let's call it msID) AspNet Identity (for user management) + IdentityServer4 (for client and resource management) + Razor (for the login page). When authentication is needed, spa redirects to the login page, the user enters the login and password, after which the redirection occurs back to spa. Spa saves id_token (reference type) and access_token. Spa makes requests with the header Bearer id_token to microservices. Microservices make requests to msID with a reference token to get user information and authorization. Everything works great.
Then we added a new spa (let's call it spaNew) and a new backend to it (msNew). spaNew works the same way as spa - it requests tokens and makes requests to msNew with the Bearer header. Also spaNew can make requests to ms1 and ms2. Everything works fine, since users are stored in msID, ​​roles and claims are also stored there.
But now we need to make it so that msNew has its own users, roles and claims. For this, it is logical to add Aspnet Identity to msNew. But authentication should still occur via msID (login page), that is, all users from msNew should also be in msID (but not all msID users should be in msNew).
It turns out that spaNew or msNew should request a token from msID, ​​and then somehow substitute claims from their own identity into it. And here we do not understand how this should work. Do we need to add our IdentityServer4 to msNew or can we somehow use a token from msID, ​​but add msNew claims to it?
